# system() call behavior

Tags: c, unix, process, system-calls

I am using system() call to start "tail -f".

One thing I saw was that, invocation of tail takes 2 processes (I can see in ps):
1) sh -c tail filename
2) tail filename

As man page says: system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command. I guess, process 1) is inevitable, correct?

I was just wondering if I can reduce number of processes from 2 to 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a picky comment about your question title: system() isn't a system call but a C library function.

Comment: @jlliagre: Very valid - title updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

system always does sh -c command. If you want only one process, do system("exec tail -f").

Comment: Thanks, but wont that eat up my current program (from which I am calling tail) too?

Comment: Nope, its not eating the current prog. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No, it'll just eat the shell.

Comment: Don't do this.  Use fork() and exec() as suggested in another answer, which is how to properly execute another binary without invoking a shell.

Comment: I voted the fork()/exec() answer up. Strictly speaking it's better unless you want shell parsing on your strings.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use `fork()/exec()` to launch processes. `system()` invokes the shell, so you should take care with what you pass to it.

```
/* Untested code, but you get the idea */
switch ((pid = fork())) {
case -1:
    perror("fork");
    break;
case 0:
    execl("/usr/bin/tail", "tail", "-f", filename);
    perror("execl");
    exit(1);
default:
    wait(pid);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very good, except for case 0 needs to call _exit(1), not exit(1).

Comment: The signature of wait is `pid_t wait(int *status)`. You'd need to use `waitpid` if you wanted to wait only for that specific pid.